# What is faster Flash or Silverlight?

Tags: performance, flash, silverlight

What is faster Flash or Silverlight? So I mean there is working [Flash quake](http://www.quake-1.com/docs/flashquake/FlashProQuake400.swf) and [Silverlight quake](http://www.innoveware.com/ql3/QuakeLight.html) (not totally working yet)

So what is faster after all? Or Are they all same speed?

really need to know to get an idea on what it’s better to start my cool programming project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how long is a piece of string? It really depends on what you're developing and what the target audience is. Bare in mind most people will have Flash installed, but many people won't have SilverLight installed as it's alot newer.

You may also want to research how Flash and SilverLight work (or don't) on mobile devices....